# Choose file download location

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

I need to allow users to download a file to their machine in my vb.net web app. I need them to browse to the download location themselves through some kind of navigation window.

For uploads I simply use a `type="file"` :

```
<input type="file" value="upload />
```

Is there an equivalent method for downloads?

Comment: can you explain your question a little?
Do you mean to say you want to allow users to download file but want to display "Save" dialog which will allow user to select location to save on there local machine?

Comment: Not really. I want a more general file-browse window, that simply allows users to see their own drive and choose a specific location. Once chosen, I want to use this path myself to use in my own customised saving method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For downloads you usually create a link:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadButton" runat="server" Text="Download report" OnClick="BtnDownloadClick" />
```

and in the code behind you stream the file to the response:

```
Protected Sub BtnDownloadClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DownloadButton.Click
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf")
    Response.Clear()
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/report.pdf"))
End Sub
```