# Using VB.net for file download and AD check

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, ftpwebrequest

Thanks for your help on this.

I've got an ftp site and web tools (vb.net) that manage the files in the site.

The ftp site and the tools use AD groups (intranet) to check permissions.

Some directories are restricted, some not so much.

On the download tool I'm using:

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(urlPath, userProfileLocal & fileNameLab.Value, domainNameHid.Value, "", True, 60000, True, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

*urlPath* might equal `ftp://ftp.net/foo/bar/myfile.zip`

For the *userProfileLocal* I'm trying to use `Dim userProfileLocal As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") & "\documents"`

*fileNameLab.Value* is pre-populated in a hidden input and is the file name

*domainNameHid.Value* is pre-populated and would look something like `DOMAIN\jimmmy`

I'm keeping the password value blank since I'm hoping to use AD.

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which says I should be using ICredentials in place of the username and password, but I'm having toubles implementing the [ICredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icredentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) part, and not even sure if this is correct.

The rest I think is accounted for.

I keep getting the error `Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied.`

*First*, that's not the path I was going for. I was hoping that `GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") & "\documents"` would create the path to the documents folder... Is there a better way to do this? Why can't one just be prompted to browse to a location or a default location be used?

*Second*,... well, second would have to do with how I don't have perms to download to my own disk. But if the firstly can be solved, then I think this will too.

I think my AD requirements are mucking up the works for what should be a simple task. Can someone point me in the right direction for an example of ICredentials (if that's what I need) or else let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to respond and let those who are looking know that I found an answer.

Instead of the code used above, I ended up using the following:

```
    Dim mydocsdir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileNameLab.Value)
            Response.Clear()
            Response.WriteFile(Path.Combine(mydocsdir, fileNameLab.Value))
```

This worked like a charm.

I need to write a special thanks to [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184291/choose-file-download-location?rq=1) who provided an answer in another post. His answer was actually the simple answer I thought it could be... but my VB.Net experience, while little now, is still growing.

Comment: One other note... for those learning VB.Net... (this will save you a lot of headaches, I think) It's easy to get methods and classes confused... some are designed to work inside of desktop applications while others designed for web forms. Sometimes it's hard to tell the difference when you are googling around and looking for a solution that will work. The not-so-easy way to tell the difference is to look at the context, are you attempting client side versus server side and where does the method/class work?